# sharing pointers via shared memory

Tags: c, pointers, ipc, shared-memory

I have rear pointer and front pointer that i need to share between the child and parent process.

```
front_ptr=(int *) shmat(shmid1,0,0);
rear_ptr=(int *) shmat(shmid1,0,0);
front=rear=-1;
front_ptr=&front;
rear_ptr=&rear;

pid1=fork();
if(pid1==0){
    while(1){
        wait(semid);
        printf("Inside wait checker\n");
        printf(" rear is %d \n",*rear_ptr);
        signal(semid);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
else{
    pid2=fork();
    if(pid2==0){
        while(1){
            wait(semid);
            printf(" rear is %d \n",*rear_ptr);
            signal(semid);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    else{
        while(1){
            wait(semid);
            printf("Insert\n");
                            insert(1,rear_ptr,front_ptr);
            printf("rear is %d \n",*rear_ptr);
            signal(semid);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Insert block it prints the correct rear pointer but the other two processes print rear as -1 and not the updated value. what is the problem that is being caused here?

Answer (score 0):

Processes usually don't share a common address space, so you can't store a pointer in shared memory and expect two different processes to see the same value through that pointer. Since your two processes come from a `fork` they use the same *values* for all pointers that have been created before the `fork`, but effectively the whole address space is copied for the child. The only region they see the same is the shared segment itself.

In fact, all the dealing with ipc is meant to circumvent this problem. If you'd attach the segments only after your `fork` and printed out the pointer value that you receive from `shmat` you'd most likely see that they are different for parent and child.

Other minor remarks on your code:

- Casts in C are almost always wrong, you shouldn't need them. Here in particular you are casting a `void*` to `int*`. Don't do that, you could just hide other subtle errors with that.
- On modern POSIX systems you have `shmopen` and `mmap` which are generally easier to use and have less restrictions than the oldish IPC calls.